# ORA-12543: TNS:destination host unreachable

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to study query optimization using SQL command line. When I'm about to connect to the database, I got this error. It's my first time to use the SQL command line. Ive installed Oracle database 11g express edition. The database I'm trying to access is also installed on my computer. I have a proxy network settings in my computer, which I already removed and the same error occurred. I'm using a desktop PC with W7 - 64bit OS. I'm using a wireless USB adapter to connect to the internet. I tried tnsping on my machine and returned the following lines:

`Used HOSTNAME adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADDRESS=(PROTO
COL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.20)(PORT=1521)))
OK (70 msec)`

Comment: are you using static ip or dynamic ip ?  check whether tns entries are done properly .

Comment: Static. Where can I check tns entries?

Comment: put your service name here.

Comment: you can find after $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin

Comment: This is a bit confusing as if you are servicing more than one database per listener, all dns aliases will default to the same database. So I would not recommend a default service name if there is more than one service name. check is there are more than one databases installed? or  you you use 10g, or 10g behavior in 11g with patch 9271246 (available only on a limited number of plateforms, os and db versions), useing 10g, or 10g behavior in 11g with patch 9271246 (available only on a limited number of platforms, os and db versions),

Comment: Is the alias you are using for `tnsping` the same as the alias you are conneting with? Shat is you `sqlplus` command address descriptor (The  '(DECRIPT...` bit) or alias, and is that that same as the descriptor/alias in the `TNSNAMES.ora` file under your `ORACLE_HOME/network/.admin` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also can you have a check to see if you have set up a loopback adapter if your os is windows. Check and follow this link

http://www.oracledistilled.com/windows/configuring-the-loopback-adapter-on-microsoft-windows/